# Why .delay() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I want to set this value `one` and then after 5 sec this value `two`  to `div`. How can I do that?

Here is what I have tried but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
$('div').html('one').delay(5000).html('two');
```

Comment: delay only works for jquery visual effects, like `fadeIn` or `slideUp`

Comment: `delay()` works on animation queues.  you could use `setTimeout()` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `setTimeout` is that it breaks nice Jquery chaining. You can keep the code fluent by wrapping immediate function in `queue` calls:

```js
$('div')
  .queue(function() {
    $(this).html('one').dequeue();
  })
  .delay(2000)
  .queue(function() {
    $(this).html('two').dequeue();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

You can even add a small "plugin" to reduce verbosity:

```
$.fn.queued = function(meth) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
      $$ = $(this);
   return this.queue(function() {
     $$[meth].apply($$, args).dequeue(); 
   });
}
```

and then:

```
$('div')
  .queued('html', 'one')
  .delay(2000)
  .queued('html', 'two')
```

Comment: Your code seems professional .. for e.x. I never seen `$$` so far :-)

Answer (score 2):

`.delay()` is used for items that are part of a queue, like animations.
You could use `.setTimeout` instead.

According to jQuery Documentation:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So, your code will be like this:

```
var temp = $('div').html('one');

setTimeout(function(){temp.html('two');}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you out?

```
$('div').html('one');

 setTimeout(function(){
        $('div').html('two');
 }, 5000);
```